# Slick Codegen With SQLServer and dbo Schema

Tags: scala, slick, slick-codegen

I am trying to use slick [codegen](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0-RC1/code-generation.html) to create a Tables.scala file based on existing data in a SQLServer with the following settings:

```
slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator.main(Array("slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile", 
                                             "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                                             "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.com:1433;applicationName=TestCodeGen;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NativeAuthentication;databaseName=MYDB", 
                                             "src/main/scala/", 
                                             "com.mypackage", 
                                             "myUserId", 
                                             ""))
```

When I run the command I get no errors but an empty Tables.scala file is produced (there are dozens of tables in the database):

```
package com.mypackage
// AUTO-GENERATED Slick data model
/** Stand-alone Slick data model for immediate use */
object Tables extends {
  val profile = slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile
} with Tables

/** Slick data model trait for extension, choice of backend or usage in the cake pattern. (Make sure to initialize this late.) */
trait Tables {
  val profile: slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
  import profile.api._
  import slick.model.ForeignKeyAction

  /** DDL for all tables. Call .create to execute. */
  lazy val schema: profile.SchemaDescription = profile.DDL(Nil, Nil)
  @deprecated("Use .schema instead of .ddl", "3.0")
  def ddl = schema
}
```

My suspicion is that there is a problem with the fact that the SQLServer is using a dbo schema but that schema is not specified anywhere in the codegen call (all of the tables are named "dbo..TableName").

So my question is: **do I need to specify 'dbo' somewhere in codegen configuration and if so, how?**

If the answer is that there is nothing that needs to be done then how to I debug the fact that codegen is obviously failing but producing no errors?

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although for direct connection the com.microsoft driver does work, I've found for code generation you need to pass in the slick jdbc SQLServerProfile with a $.

```
Array("slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile", 
        "slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile$",
        "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.com:1433;applicationName=TestCodeGen;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NativeAuthentication;databaseName=MYDB", 
        "src/main/scala/", 
        "com.mypackage", 
        "myUserId", 
        "")
```

If that doesn't work, try also adding a jtds driver to your library, and using a jtds styled url:

```
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myserver.com:1433;applicationName=TestCodeGen;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NativeAuthentication;databaseName=MYDB"
```

Where your jtds dependency would look like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.3.1"
```